# linking C code with Fortran module.function()

Tags: c, fortran, dynamic-linking

I have to build a C shared library (.so) under Solaris, in order to use it as a DLM (Dynamic Loadable Module) from Exelis IDL language.

This C library must use some Fortran f90 functions, included in Fortran modules.

I could compile both C and Fortran code (with -fpic, -G, ...) but I have a problem to call fortran libraries from C.

In my .so files, Fortran functions included in modules are named
module.function

eg: 
$ nm idl_spi.so
[290] |...|FUNC |GLOB |0 |15  spi_m_libscient.spi_scient_init_common_

In my C code, I can't use any of :

spi_scient_init_common_()

=> Symbol not found in the library (uncomplete name)

spi_m_libscient.spi_scient_init_common_()

=> unknown structure spi_m_libscient

Is there a way to call a Fortran module_name.function_name() from C ?

Or to change Fortran behaviour when compiling module.function(),
to rename for example module__function in the objet file

I could find any f90 command line option

Comment: Can you change the Fortran code, to use for example [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding]?

Comment: Yeah, setting the binding name by `bind(C, name="your_name")` is the way to go.

Comment: Many thanks. Il have just added bind(C) after my function declaration and it works now

Comment: I saw that iso_c_binding appears with Fortran 2003, whereas I'm using F95

Comment: Is there any strong reason you have to strictly remain at F95 in 2016?